# Activating jquery tabber based on the clicked navigation link

Tags: javascript, jquery

my website has a navigation with an id `#nav`. I want to activate a tabber based on the clicked navigation list. The navigation `#nav` has an html like this:-

```
 <ul id ="nav">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Fred</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Thom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Kay</a></li>
</ul>
```

when Fred is clicked from the navigation, I want to activate this on the tabber which has an html like this

```
 <ul class="tabs">                                        
         <li><a href="#tab1">Fred</a></li>                                      
         <li><a href="#tab2">Thom</a></li>    
         <li><a href="#tab3">Kay</a></li>       
</ul>
```

and tab content like this:-

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">Lorem</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">Ipsum</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab_content">Dolor</div>
```

so I wrote the following line of jquery

```
$("#nav li").click(function() {

         var hash = location.hash;
          var sel = $("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "'], ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']");

    if (sel.length) { 

        sel.addClass("active").parent().addClass("active"); //Activate tab



        $(hash).show();
    }
```

it doesn't work! And how do I bind the onclick event to it? Sorry guys, I'm pretty new to jquery. I've seen previous examples on this site which doesn't work when I try to use. So can someone adapt my code/help me out please?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that shows what your HTML looks like before clicking? (i.e. CSS). I'm assuming that certain parts are hidden to begin with, but you're not really giving much to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery isn't the problem - it's your HTML. You're using location.hash in the click function, but your nav ul doesn't actually have hashes. Try changing this:

```
<ul id ="nav">
    <li><a href="tab1">Fred</a></li>
    <li><a href="tab2">Thom</a></li>
    <li><a href="tab3">Kay</a></li>
</ul>
```

to this:

```
<ul id ="nav">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Fred</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Thom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Kay</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it's a typo, I fixed it .. can you help me out please? still not working